# Battlefield 4 Commander - Deployment of Gunship

Tags: battlefield-4

Yesterday when I played Battlefield 4 in the commander role on an Ipad, a deployment of a Gunship immediately caused a vehicle on the map to be destroyed, sort of similar to firing a missile but without the delay. This happened once more in the game.

My question is: **As a commander in Battlefield 4, is firing a gunship on a target through aiming the deployment "on top" the target an undocumented feature of the game?**

Perhaps it is a programming mistake since gunships and missiles seem to have similar behaviour from the commanders point of view.

Comment: deployed gunship is manned by team members, may be someone spawned in it and make kill?

Comment: Though my experience of Commanding, the "Deploy Gunship" option only circles around the capture point that controls it's use (typically C). I tried deploying above a different control point where there was a lot of enemy armor and also above the half-sunken ship on Paracel Storm, however it always spawned and circled in the same place. You will get kill assists/vehicle destroy assists if a team member kills a unit though. I might be mis-interpreting your question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deploy a gunship while the enemy has a gunship already out, you will do damage to it over time. You had good timing and was able to do the remaining bit of damage needed. If there are any remaining passengers, the commander who deployed the new gunship will get the kills.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good explanation of what I experienced.